# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have installed AJAXcontrolsToolkit with my visual studio and placed "Combobox" Ajaxcontrol controls in my webpage . when i am compiling the code getting below error

"Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: i have noticed when i register AJAX controls assembly need to give the assembly name,version,culture,publickeytoken 
ex:
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the required assembly to the references of your project?

Comment: @Jeyavel : Is the problem resolved now or are you still facing the same assembly load error

Answer (score 1):

The above post was very useful

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

I was using the above code , i replaced  the code as below and now working

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Thanks for your post

Answer (score 1):

I use File-Zilla to upload my files to the web server. I found that my reference files  (AjaxControlToolkit.dll and AjaxControlToolkit.pdb) in the bin folder on the web server had not been completely transferred.   so I deleted them and I uploaded new ones from the development site  directly into the bin folder of the web server.

And Voila!  Everything just fell into place like magic.

Answer (score 0):

The application not load because it not find or not is compatible, try to do download from at nuget  Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit -version x.x, or in site.