# Could not load file or assembly 'jquerycalendar' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server

I have hosted website on Windows sever and It is showing error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'jquerycalendar' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It is working fine on local server but not on Hosting Server. What can be the wrong ?

I google to solve this problem but I dint find anything.
Is it related to coding work or hosting server ?

Comment: How is the assembly referenced?  Does the assembly exist on the server?

Comment: I have uploaded Bin folder which was created at the time of ajax used.

Comment: @JeetenParmar yes, but is `jquerycalendar.dll` actually **in** the `bin` folder on the server?

Comment: @David, no, it is not there. Even it is not on local server they it is working here ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar It may be in your `%PATH%`, which would allow your local installation to see it. However, if it is not deployed to the server, your app will not be able to load it (as it does not exist). Make sure it is included as a reference in Visual Studio, rebuild your solution, and redeploy it. Speaking of which, how are you deploying? One-click, FTP, ?? This error basically means `File Not Found: jqueryCalendar.dll`

Comment: I rebuild it in Visual Studio and uploaded it through FTP.

Comment: Yes, but what are you uploading? I hope it's not your source folder? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfx5as36.ASPX for more information on FTP publishing in VS.

Comment: @David, Yes, sir. It is source folder only. And I am doing it from the last more than 2 years.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50040/discussion-between-david-lively-and-jeeten-parmar)

Answer (score 0):

That error is .NET-speak for `File Not Found: jqueryCalendar.DLL.`

1. Is the assembly included in your Visual Studio solution? If not, depending upon how it is referenced, it may not be deployed.
2. Have you verified that the assembly in question exists on the server, in the `bin` folder where your project is deployed?
3. Also, see these other questions, which all popped up in the "Related" column when I was posting this:

   - [Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844443/)
   - [Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362365)
   - [Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081677)

Comment: where should i find this file or how can I add reference of this file in my project ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar in VS, right-click on the `references` item under your web application project in the Solution Explorer, and click `Add Reference.` Click `Browse`, and browse to the location where you've installed jqueryCalendar.dll. It may also be in the `Assemblies` tab in the resulting dialog.