# Parser Error: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image]

As the image shows, I have been not able to run the application in `localhost`.

Everything seems fine.

What I've tried:

- Deleting/readding the references and make sure they are copied into the `bin` folder.
- Make sure that everything is running .NET 4.0
- I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832256/1188208) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1905229/1188208)
- I also tried creating another Application Pool running V4.0
- And *Convert to Application*

What else can I do?

Thank you

**Update:**

I registered the file using:

`<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />`

But, it's still complaining that the file is not there! It is there!

Comment: Did you registered ajax in your page?

Comment: Hey @NiMa thanks for your input. Check my update. I added the line. But, now it's saying that "The system cannot find the file specified." (Silly because its referenced) Any ideas?

Comment: well the assembly added in the webconfig right?but did you register your assembly in aspx page?

Comment: Please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695657/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-ajaxcontroltoolkit-or-one-of-its-depende

Comment: I have one question, where did you get the ajax controltoolkit from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after trying a lot, I noticed that there was a problem with the Ouput path of the application. I just put everything in `bin\`

That magically fixed everything. I still don't know how because the `.dll` was in the correct position before.

All the other stuff that I tried was completely useless.

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in your local and not working in server means there is a chance of environment issue like 32bit/64 bit.

So just check the application pool advanced settings.

Enable 32-Bit applications make it to true and try once.

[image]

cheers,
vijay